# Detecting geo location asp.net mvc - hosted in amazon aws

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, dns, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I have an asp.net mvc application hosted in amazon aws. Is there a service in amazon that sets the geo location of each request in a header or server variable which i can access in code and show personalized stuff ?

Is there some other dns service I can use that will give me this data as a header variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not aware of any services provided in AWS.

However, there is 3rd party commercial HTTP module that you can install inside IIS such as http://www.ip2location.com/software/http-module

You can get the country code from server variable "HTTP_X_COUNTRY_SHORT". There are also other variables available.